# googleCloudStorageR::gcs_auth: Error: Non-interactive session and no authentication email selected

Tags: r, google-authentication, bigrquery, gargle, google-cloud-storage-r

I'd like to use this function in docker to authenticate Biq Query and Google Cloud Storage.

```
authenticate <- function() {
    scopes <- c("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')
    token <- gargle::token_fetch(scopes = scopes)
    bigrquery::bq_auth(token = token)
    googleCloudStorageR::gcs_auth(token = token, token)
}
```

I append my credentials to docker from `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`. `bq_auth` works fine. If I run the function outside the docker, it works fine but I have to interactively sign in.

With docker, I get an error

```
Error: Non-interactive session and no authentication email selected.
         
Setup JSON service email auth or specify email in gar_auth(email='me@preauthenticated.com')
```

Even if I passed my email to `gcs_auth`, it didn't work (but I'd like to avoid that).